# opengl-es shader language if statement vs?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I read that in a fragment shader you shouldn't use if statements as they reduce performance. I found this in a fragment shader however

```
gl_FragColor.a = (gl_FragColor.a > uAlphaThreshold) ? gl_FragColor.a : 0.0;
```

Which I think means this

```
if(gl_FragColor.a > uAlphaThreshold){
     gl_FragColor.a = 0.0
}
```

Does the original statement give you a performance boost?

Comment: Logically it should't,So same performance for both the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that there will be much of a difference. They are just two different notations, but it's a branch in either case.

The two statements in your question are **not** the same, though. The equivalent to:

```
gl_FragColor.a = (gl_FragColor.a > uAlphaThreshold) ? gl_FragColor.a : 0.0;
```

is:

```
if (gl_FragColor.a <= uAlphaThreshold){
    gl_FragColor.a = 0.0
}
```

Note the different comparison operator compared to your code. With the ternary operator, the first value (`gl_FragColor.a`) is used if the condition is true, the second value (`0.0`) is used if it's false. So you need to invert the condition when turning it into an `if` statement.

If you want to avoid a branch, you could use the built-in `step()` function:

```
gl_FragColor.a = step(uAlphaThreshold, gl_FragColor.a) * gl_FragColor.a;
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator (?:) in your case expands to this:

```
if(gl_FragColor.a > uAlphaThreshold){
     gl_FragColor.a = gl_FragColor.a; // will be probably optimized out
}
else {
     gl_FragColor.a = 0.0;
}
```

So the answer is: there is no performance boost, just two ways to write the same code.